# Dispatch touch event with the same access level as user input

Tags: android, touch, desktop

I would like to know whether not it is possible to dispatch touch events that are treated by the os as the same as user input (ie: the touch event will be recognized by all apps). I want to achieve an effect similar to puppetmaster (used to remotely control devices from a desktop).

While android probably prevents this for security would it be possible to implement a workaround? Such as using an invisible view controlled by my own app while allowing touch events from this view to "bleed" through to all views behind it.

Has anyone implemented anything like this?

My end goal is to have a puppetmaster- like software capable of remote controlling the phone from the desktop.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> While android probably prevents this for security would it be possible to implement a workaround?

With root permissions, you can use whatever the VNC server software for Android uses, presumably low-level Linux events.

Without root permissions, this should be impossible, for obvious security reasons. One app cannot control the UI of another app.